# Can Grails route requests to different controller by *method*?

Tags: grails, routes, url-mapping

I have a URL that I'd like to handle with different controllers depending on the method. Is there a way to do this via `UrlMappings`?

Using two different mappings for the same URL doesn't work (the second overwrites the first)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but can you try with the below mapping:

```
"/myurl" {
    if(params.method == "doThis"){
        controller = "doThis"
        action = "doThisAction"
    } else if(params.method == "doThat"){
        controller = "doThat"
        action = "doThatAction"
    }
}
```

Assuming,

```
http://<appserver>/myurl?method=doThis
http://<appserver>/myurl?method=doThat
```

**UPDATE**
When referring to HTTP Methods you can use filter (where we have request available) as below:

```
class RoutingFilters{
    def filters = {
        routingCheck(uri: '/myurl/**' ) {
            before = {
                if(request.method == 'GET'){
                    redirect(controller: 'doThis', action: 'doThis')
                }

                if(request.method == 'POST'){
                    redirect(controller: 'doThat', action: 'doThat') 
                }

                //So on and so forth for PUT and DELET

                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

provided the url mapping would look something like:

```
//defaulting to "doThis" or any other "valid" controller as dummy
"/myurl/$id?"(controller: 'doThis')
```

Comment: I think he's talking about HttpMethod.  So a url like "/myurl", but hit using GET would hit one controller, hit with POST would hit a different one.  Your code should be close, only need to check the HttpMethod instead of some "method" param

Comment: ... and I'm not sure how to check the HttpMethod at runtime -- e.g. in the closure, there is no `request` variable available.

Comment: Filtering on what? Related question (including workaround) about filters/method at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837230/does-grails-filter-actionexclude-work-with-method-based-routing

Comment: @Bosh See my update. Give me few minutes to look at the other question.

Comment: Upvoted for a viable workaround, but to clarify: is the answer to my question simply "No, this can't be done with UrlMappings"?

Comment: I was facing the same problem in UrlMapping, as you did, getting the `request`. Filter was the choice because it has got all those necessary items available already. I did not play with `ServletContext` in `UrlMapping` because I know using filters will be a cleaner approach. AFAIK, "no" this can't be done in UrlMapping. @Bosh