# Does Grails Filter `actionExclude` work with method-based routing?

Tags: grails, routes, url-mapping, grails-filters

I have a method-based route like:

```
name base: "/" {
  controller="api"
  action=[GET: "welcome", POST: "post"]
}
```

And I'd like to apply a filter to handle authorization, e.g.

```
class RequestFilters {
    def filters = {
        authorizeRequest(controller: 'api', actionExclude: 'welcome') {
            before = {
                log.debug("Applying authorization filter.")
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

But when I apply this in practice, the filter runs on all requests (even GET requests, which should use the `welcome` method and thus should not trigger this filter.)

When I inspect the code running the in the filter, I see that `params.action` is set to the Map from my routing file, rather than to "welcome".  Not sure if this is related to the issue.

My current workaround (which feels very wrong) is to add the following to my filter's *body*:

```
if(params.action[request.method] == 'welcome'){
    return true
}
```

The short question is: does Grails support this combination of method-based routing + action-name-based filtering?  If so, how? If not, what are some reasonable alternatives for restructuring this logic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the filter as below:

```
class RequestFilters {
    def filters = {
        authorizeRequest(controller:'api', action:'*', actionExclude:'welcome'){
            before = {
                log.debug("Applying authorization filter.")
                return true
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Apply the filter to `all` actions of the controller `but` "welcome". :)

If there is no other `welcome` action in the other controllers then, you would not need the controller specified in the filter as well.

```
authorizeRequest(action:'*', actionExclude:'welcome'){...}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (the closure is invoked even for the `welcome` action). Does it work for you?

Comment: Well that's my luck. What grails version?

Comment: @Bosh Grails 2.2.4. I do not have the sample code right now, but I can forward that to you later in the evening, once home. Right now, you can create a sample app and test the same.

Comment: Thanks -- I will create a clean sample app with Grails 2.2.4 and  report the outcome!

Comment: No luck: I just created a clean sample app with Grails `2.2.4` with one controller + one filter using the exact syntax you supply above.  The closure is called even for the `welcome` action, using the `UrlMappings` that I describe in the initial post.

Comment: @Bosh [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6121741/) are the main items from my sample app which I used yesterday. Are you using `curl` for GET/POST? I used Chrome's [Rest Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en) extension to test for GET/POST and they worked as expected. If required I can send you the snapshots. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does -- looks like a typo in my arguments. Thanks much for your patience!